# Please can you explain the process to the result

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] tab = new int[3][3];
        int s1 = 0;
        int s2 = 0;

        tab[0][0]=8;
        tab[0][1]=5;
        tab[0][2]=7;
        tab[1][0]=9;
        tab[1][1]=3;
        tab[1][2]=2;
        tab[2][0]=4;
        tab[2][1]=6;
        tab[2][2]=1;

        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++){
            s1 += tab[i][2];
            s2 += tab[2][i];
        }
        System.out.println(s1 + " " + s2);
    }
}
```

Anyone can explain why the result is `10 11`?

How the code is going on through this 2D array?

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: Or even following it with pen and paper.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to dry run your code, debug it line by line.

Here is the explanation you need.

```
s1 = 0
i=0
s1 += tab[i][2]; 
=> s1 = 0+tab[0][2] 
=> s1 = 0+7
=> s1 = 7

s1 = 7
i=1
s1 += tab[i][2]; 
=> s1 = 7+tab[1][2] 
=> s1 = 7+2
=> s1 = 9

s1 = 9
i=2
s1 += tab[i][2]; 
=> s1 = 9+tab[2][2] 
=> s1 = 9+1
=> s1 = 10
```

Same for s2 ( 4+6+1 =11)

Hence `s1,s2 => 10,11`